# Convergence of one sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$  is sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-4|=3$ then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ must converge to what?

The answer is undecided but I can't understand why?

Is it a hint or clarification that helps me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

It is undecided because:

1. if $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):x_n=7$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=7$;
2. if $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):x_n=1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$;
3. if $x_n=7$ if $n$ is odd and $x_n=1$ otherwise, then the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ does not exist.

And in each case $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-3|=4$.

Comment: When  the questions without  absolute like $ x_n -4 →3  is it undecided or covergence to 7 ?

Comment: @FatimHasan Then it converges to $7$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $x_n=1$ for all $n$. Then $|x_n-4|=3 \to 3$, as $n \to \infty$, $(x_n)$ is convergent.
2. Let $x_n=4+3(-1)^n$. Then $|x_n-4|\to 3$, as $n \to \infty$, $(x_n)$ is divergent.